# Set C compiler in a C++ project

Tags: c++, c, eclipse-cdt

ALL,

I have a C++ RHEL8 project and we use Eclipse as an IDE.

However some files here are written in pure C (dissectors) and there fore has to be built with the C compiler.

Is it possible to tell Eclipse that those files are built with C compiler rather then C++, and then re-index them differently?

I know MSVC has such an option, but what about Eclipse?

TIA!!

Comment: I’m confused. Are you asking about eclipse or gcc? Eclipse, to the best of my knowledge, doesn’t compile anything. Or are you asking for them to be treated differently only in the ide. I.e for static analysis purposes. Etc.

Comment: @Taekahn, the latter.I need the Eclipse to index files differently and that is I believe is a static analysis.

Comment: The default builder and gcc tool set-up for eclipse splits the rules for C and C++ compilers and selects the appropriate compiler based on the extension of the file. Give the C files .c extensions and Eclipse should figure itself out.